# definining own teaser text for post

Tags: posts, content

i'd like to have a small news box in my sidebar - so i need to display just a few lines of text, separated from the actual the_content() - how could i do that?
it should be somekind of quicktag which will be hidden in the full post content.

thanks

Comment: Use the excerpt field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this widget: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recent-posts-with-excerpts/

Comment: thanks for your answer - how can i activate the excerpt box? it's not visible at the editor .. :/

Comment: click screen options at the top of the editor page - the excerpt field is probably unchecked